# include div in foreach just in some condition

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have some **navbar** with `menu` and `submenu`, I want to appear some `<div>` in that **menu** to appear the submenu just if this menu has submenu items

The div that I want to appear are div1, div2, div3, see comments and in this condition : `<?php if ($men["titre"] == $sub["parentmenu"]) : ?>`

I can't put them in this foreach :  `<?php foreach($submenu as $sub) :?>` because I need that three div just ones for all the submenu `<li>`

**Exemple** of one menu who have submenus:

```
<li class="Menu1">
    <a class="header-menu " href="#">Menu1 title</a> //Menu1
    <div class="mobile-header-nav-submenu-container"> //div 1
        <ul class="mobile-header-nav-submenu"> //div 2
            <div class="mobile-header-nav-submenu-li-container"> //div3
                <li class="submenu1">
                    <a class="" href="#">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu2">
                    <a class="" href="#">Submenu2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu3">
                    <a class="" href="#">Submenu3</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**My code:**

```
<div class="menu>
    <?php foreach ($menu as $men): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $men["titre"]?>">
            <a class="header-menu <?php echo $men["lien"]?>" href="<?php if($men["lien"]){echo $baseUrl.$men["lien"];}else{echo '#';}?>"><?php echo $men["titre"]?></a>
            <div class="mobile-header-nav-submenu-container"> //div1
                <ul class="mobile-header-nav-submenu"> //div2
                    <div class="mobile-header-nav-submenu-li-container"> //div3
                        <?php foreach($submenu as $sub) :?>
                            <?php if ($men["titre"] == $sub["parentmenu"]) : ?>
                                <li id="<?php echo $sub["titre"]?>" class="mobile-header-nav-submenu-li">
                                    <a class="" href="<?php if($sub["lien"]){echo $baseUrl.$sub["lien"];}else{echo '#';}?>">
                                        <?php echo $sub["titre"]?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what's an issue you are facing here? What is incorrect happening?

Comment: If you don't have already, you will need a multi-dimensional array in order to loop over the menus, and then the sub menus

Comment: You cannot put div 3 directly below the ul - swap div 3 and the ul around and the html will be valid (you will probably need to swap around some css too)

Comment: Whats happenig here with my code is that all my menu contains that three divs `div1, div2, div3` and as I said I want to appear them just if my menu have submenu items, and to know if my menu have submenu items is with this condition : `<?php if ($men["titre"] == $sub["parentmenu"]) : ?>`